# Prepopulate individual search column: Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have an application that will pass the filtering attributes in the url  `http://localhost/webpage/public/index.php?control_id=123&sample_id=234`

I'm using javascript to identify the id:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const control_id = urlParams.get('control_id');
const sample_id = urlParams.get('sample_id');
```

I want to pass the control_id and sample_id in the column filtering field in my data table
[cloumn filtering box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuCeC.png)

But I'm not being able to do so, I added `"oSearch": {"sSearch": control_id},`  to the data table, but this is filtering the universal search of the table.
[universal search filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD57y.png)

How can I filter data based on column filtering and not the universal filtering in data tables?

Appreciate your time.

--UPDATE--

This is the definition of data tables JS

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

            $(document).ready(function() {
                const control_id = urlParams.get('control_id');
                // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
                $('#example tfoot th').each(function () {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
                });
                $('#example').DataTable( {
                    "oSearch": {"sSearch": control_id},
                    "processing": true,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "searching":true,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "order": [[0, 'asc']],
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "../model/Data.php",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "dataType": "json",
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        {data: 'control_id'},
                        {data: 'sample_id'},
                        {data: 'sample_nm'},
                        {data: 'sample_type_nm'},
                        {data: 'variant_type'},
                        {data: 'pipeline_status'},
                        {data: 'oncsuite_status'},
                        {data: 'control_completion_status'},
                        {data: 'send_oncsuite_status'},
                        {data: 'api_log_creation_dt'}
                    ],
                });
                var table = $('#example').DataTable();
                table.columns().every( function () {
                    var that = this;
                    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    } );
                } );
            });
```

The version of datatbales is : `1.10.22`

Comment: Please update your question and show us the definition of your datatable in JS.  Also, what version of datatables are you using?  `oSearch` is legacy datatables...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors in your code.  First, you're initializing your DataTable more than one time.  Instead, init it once and assign it to a variable, like so:

```
var myTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "searching":true,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "order": [[0, 'asc']],
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "../model/Data.php",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "dataType": "json",
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        {data: 'control_id'},
                        {data: 'sample_id'},
                        {data: 'sample_nm'},
                        {data: 'sample_type_nm'},
                        {data: 'variant_type'},
                        {data: 'pipeline_status'},
                        {data: 'oncsuite_status'},
                        {data: 'control_completion_status'},
                        {data: 'send_oncsuite_status'},
                        {data: 'api_log_creation_dt'}
                    ],
                });
```

Then, to search filter by `control_id` and `sample_id`:

```
myTable.column(0).search(control_id).column(1).search(sample_id).draw();
```

To explain: `myTable` contains your DataTable object. You then define which column to search using the column index (which starts at 0 for the first column), and you can chain your filters together like I've shown above.

**Notes:**

- This assumes you want an `AND` condition for your filter, so that the
  results returned must have both filter criteria met (`control_id` AND
  `sample_id`), which follows the logic of your url parameters.
- This assumes that that variables `control_id` and `sample_id` are in
  scope of the line of code above.

Here is a [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/058s7Lnp/10/)

Comment: Thank you Sir, I have a lot of homework to do on datatables. Appreciate your explanation and help.

Comment: @JP_93 - I'm not a sir, but you're welcome!